# Auditing for migration tool flyway, mongobee with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, javers

I am using spring boot app with mongodb, and postgres. And use spring data to interact with db. Need auditing for the changes which happen in the app. Currently exploring javers to do this. But is there any way where i can achieve auditing at migration level as well.

Comment: what exactly do you want to audit? migration via Flyway happens via specified user and connection.. there's no session-based interaction on this level (boot-time nor deploy-time). Flyway offers a log itsself, also pre- and post-scripts, maybe this can help you?

Comment: So lets say if there is a user table, and having one row with some pk-20 created by flywayscript, and later on got updated by another script. Now want to have audit for each field of user table here.

Comment: so you want to see a "Diff" between the two versions? in the log, in the table or elsewhere? imho you should know what your Flyway scripts do and you can track them pretty well using the `flyway_migration_history` table (or whatever you name it). no need for an audit there.

Comment: Hmm, flyway_schema_history just stores the script name, version, checksum etc. Doesn't store the difference between old vs new object of given entity. I want to have changes audit for all the entities for given app. Now changes can happen through regular spring data or flyway migration sript.

Comment: ok, thanks. now I see what you want to achieve. although I question the fact you're overriding user-editted data via Flyway a bit xD I'd maybe rather think of a DB-based solution (like [`TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html)). but I have honestly never done this (auditting Flyway, I mean).